# How to get the id's of html element of html document in c# using html agility pack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have something like this

```
<div class='mainclass subclass1' quest-id='123'> </div>
<div class='mainclass subclass2' quest-id='234'> </div>
<input quest-id='3236'> </input>
<textarea quest-id='256'> </textarea>
```

I want the `quest-d` of all div which belongs to class named `subclass1`, `subclass2` and `quest-id` of all input and textarea.  How can i do it using html agility pack in c#?

and i have c# code like this:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(obj.NewPage.Content);

HtmlNode htmlRootElement = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html");
HtmlNode bodyElement = htmlRootElement.SelectSingleNode("body");
```

i dont know how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet I wrote and tested.

```
 const string sampleHTML = @"<div class='mainclass subclass1' quest-id='123'></div>
    <div class='mainclass subclass2' quest-id='234'></div>
    <input quest-id='3236'> </input>
    <textarea quest-id='256'> </textarea>";


 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument myDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 myDoc.LoadHtml(sampleHTML);
 HtmlNodeCollection foundNodes = myDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/div[contains(@class, 'subclass2')]");                                                                         
 MessageBox.Show(foundNodes[0].Attributes["quest-id"].Value);
```

When I run the snippet, I see the value '234' in the message box.

Answer (score 0):

Following XPath can get all quest-id value from sample html posted in this question :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'subclass1') or contains(@class, 'subclass2')]
| //input[@quest-id] 
| //textarea[@quest-id]
```

Working example :

```
var html = @"<root><div class='mainclass subclass1' quest-id='123'> </div>
<div class='mainclass subclass2' quest-id='234'> </div>
<input quest-id='3236'> </input>
<textarea quest-id='256'> </textarea></root>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var nodes = 
    doc.DocumentNode
       .SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'subclass1') or contains(@class, 'subclass2')]"
                        + " | //input[@quest-id] "
                        + " | //textarea[@quest-id]");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.GetAttributeValue("quest-id", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string id = div.GetAttributeValue("id", "").ToString();
 string name= div.GetAttributeValue("name", "").ToString();
```